# EF6 - Generating unneeded nested queries

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I have the following tables:

```
MAIN_TBL:
Col1 | Col2 | Col3
------------------
A    | B    | C
D    | E    | F
```

And:

```
REF_TBL:
Ref1 | Ref2 | Ref3
------------------
A    | G1   | Foo
D    | G1   | Bar
Q    | G2   | Xyz
```

I wish to write the following SQL query:

```
SELECT    M.Col1
FROM      MAIN_TBL M
LEFT JOIN REF_TBL R
ON        R.Ref1 = M.Col1 
AND       R.Ref2 = 'G1'
WHERE     M.Col3 = 'C'
```

I wrote the following LINQ query:

```
from main in dbContext.MAIN_TBL
join refr in dbContext.REF_TBL
on "G1" equals refr.Ref2
into refrLookup
from refr in refrLookup.DefaultIfEmpty()
where main.Col1 == refr.Col1
select main.Col1
```

And the generated SQL was:

```
SELECT 
    [MAIN_TBL].[Col1]
    FROM  (SELECT 
    [MAIN_TBL].[Col1] AS [Col1],
    [MAIN_TBL].[Col2] AS [Col2],
    [MAIN_TBL].[Col3] AS [Col3]
    FROM [MAIN_TBL]) AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN (SELECT 
    [REF_TBL].[Ref1] AS [Ref1],
    [REF_TBL].[Ref2] AS [Ref2],
    [REF_TBL].[Ref3] AS [Ref3]
    FROM [REF_TBL]) AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Col1] = [Extent2].[Ref1]
    WHERE ('G1' = [Extent2].[DESCRIPTION]) AND ([Extent2].[Ref1] IS NOT NULL) AND CAST( [Extent1].[Col3] AS VARCHAR) = 'C') ...
```

Looks like it is nesting a query within another query, while I just want it to pull from the table. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The query looks totally OK. The nesting has zero impact on performance. Do you have an actual performance problem or did this just look suspicious?

Comment: No, I ran both queries one after the other and the EF generated query had a cost of 80%, while the one I wrote was 20%.

Comment: The queries are semantically different. They filter on different columns, one has LEFT JOIN the other INNER JOIN. They are incomparable. You seem to think that the nesting causes a perf problem. This nesting does not exist in the final execution plan. It disappears. When I said "zero" I meant it literally.

Comment: Are your sure this is really what you want ? Why the hell would you left join on a table that you don't use in the select clause ? Just to get multiple identical result where there's something in the left joined table ? By the way, totally agree with @usr . If you do a where on the left join table in linq, this will do an inner join.

Answer (score 2):

I may be wrong, but it looks like you don't do the same in linq query and sql query, especially on your left joining clause.

I would go for this, if you want something similar to your sql query.

```
from main in dbContext.MAIN_TBL.Where(x => x.Col3 == "C")
join refr in dbContext.REF_TBL
on new{n = "G1", c = main.Col1} equals new{n = refr.Ref2, c = refr.Col1}
   into refrLookup
from r2 in refrLookup.DefaultIfEmpty()
select main.Col1
```

By the way, it doesn't make much sense to left join on a table which is not present in the select clause : you will just get multiple identical Col1 if there's more than one related item in the left joined table...

Comment: Thanks, let me try this out.. I am indeed going to be selecting the reference column in left join.

Comment: That brings down the cost of the EF query to 79%, whereas the regular query is 21% of the cost when executed in one batch. Doesn't matter which order they are executed.

Comment: 1. How does the EF's generated SQl looks like, now ? 2. Have you got a real performance problem in your application because of that query ?

Comment: It now has a left outer join instead of the inner join, the query still looks the same. I cannot measure if there's a performance issue until we deploy it in prod, but I'd like to be on the safe side and prevent sending the code if the higher query cost could potentially have performance issues.